# Drawing Interactive paths in JavaFX 8?

Tags: input, path, drawing, javafx-8

(please excuse any mistakes in the way of questioning/ formatting the question since I'm new)

[Please Note that I cannot post code here as yet, and FXML code isnt worth posting right ?
Also, my GUI programming experience before this is very little... I picked up JavaFX 8 first because I use Java, and heard that FX >> Swing in many ways]

I am trying to make a GUI that allows the user to input the NumberLink puzzle numbers (through mouse action events), and then, displays the puzzle in a grid with features to draw a path, and undo it. This is almost exactly the same functionality as in [Numberlink on Nikoli](http://www.nikoli.com/swf/nl.swf?loadUrl=/nfp/nl-0001.nfp&lang=1). The puzzle is quite interesting, and these are the [rules](http://www.nikoli.com/en/puzzles/numberlink/rule.html). The goal of the UI is for the user to interactively solve the puzzle by drawing lines,etc, just as on Nikoli's site. The solver will be a later addition.

1. In my project, I have a `Stage` in which a setup `Scene` prompts user for rows and columns (to take size of puzzle),
2. next, it generates an empty grid (I'm thinking of using a `GridPane` here), and the user clicks the squares to enter the numbers into the square. this phase isnt a problem if I use `TextField`s and mouse listeners and store info in a grid... the next phase is what I'm stuck at... unless I know exactly how to do that, I cant make progress...
3. in the third stage, I have to display the numbers to the user just like on the Nikoli site (the highlighting number pairs on mouse hover is a necessary feature too, which I think I can handle with CSS).. and the user should draw paths between the numbers, just as on that site ( I thought `VLineTo` and `HLineTo` classes would be suitable.. but I'm not sure, and cant find any alternatives) Please help on this ...

So with this in mind, I made FXML based dummy gui layouts to test if my ideas work...
and I cant get the GridPane to have lines drawing atop it (meaning, I cant place Line objects like `HLineTo` on top of the grid panes).... **is there any other way to do what I need to do** ?
I also thought of making multiple `Canvas` objects in a grid (each square is its own canvas), having the numbers as `Text` objects, and a Canvas on top of the grid with transparency ON, and having them both on a `StackPane`, but then, the `StackPane`'s children will not be synchronised.

Please help point me in the right direction, thanks (tell me if I'm missing something basic, which I think I am).

Comment: You should always be able to post code...

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `GridPane` in an `AnchorPane`, then use `getChildren().add(Node node)`.

Assuming your controller has defined `<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorpane"...>` and `implements Initializable`

```
@FXML private AnchorPane anchorpane;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    Line line = new Line(double startX, double startY, double endX, double endY);

    anchorpane.getChildren.add(line);
}
```

**NOTE**: The line should actually be dependent on mouse events, so it really shouldn't even be in your initialize method; but it should help you get started with what you want to do.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! It's a nice idea to wrap the `GridPane` in an `AnchorPane` and draw atop it. let me try it out and get back to you.